# How to replace all Active Directory account photos?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a powershell script to replace a single photo:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$photo = [byte[]](Get-Content C:\scripts\foto\XXX.jpg -Encoding byte)
Set-ADUser XXX -Replace @{thumbnailPhoto=$photo}
```

I have a text file with the usernames of the accounts in:

```
ROB ALAN COY GREGOR
```

I want to automate replacing all photo in Active Directory. How would I do this?

Comment: Is that actually what your text file looks like? A single row that is space delimited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could't comprehend Ashigore's probably right one-liner. Here it is broken down line by line into a foreach loop.

```
$users = get-adUser
foreach ($user in $users){
   $photoPath = "C:\scripts\foto\$($_.SamAccountName).jpg"
   if (Test-Path $photoPath ) {
       $photo = Get-Content "C:\scripts\foto\$($user.SamAccountName).jpg" -Encoding byte
       Set-ADUser $user -Replace @{thumbnailPhoto=$photo}
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest if you want to replace all users photos to do something more like this:

```
Get-ADUser | Where-Object { Test-Path "C:\scripts\foto\$($_.SamAccountName).jpg" } | Set-ADUser -Replace @{thumbnailPhoto=(Get-Content "C:\scripts\foto\$($_.SamAccountName).jpg" -Encoding byte)}
```

While untested. this should set the photo for all users where a picture exists in the path with their username.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a little bit better:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter *
foreach ($user in $users){
$photoPath = "C:\foto\$($user.SamAccountName).jpg"
if (Test-Path $photoPath ) {
$photo = Get-Content "C:\foto\$($user.SamAccountName).jpg" -Encoding byte
Set-ADUser $user -Replace @{thumbnailPhoto=([byte[]]$photo)}
Write-Host 'Foto was set for:' $user.SamAccountName}}
```

With best regards, Dmitrii.

P.S.
Eric's code is taken as a basis.

Comment: Given the other code has already been accepted, it would be useful for you to describe what makes your solution better.  More reliable, better logging, more readable?